# Eclipselink - JPA 2.0 - Select with lockMode and maxResult doesn't work

Tags: java, orm, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

```
@Override
public List<Sample> getSampleRecords() {
    List<Sample> samples = null;
    try {

        Query query = entityManager
                .createQuery(
                        "from Sample s order by s.createdAt desc")
                .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
         query.setMaxResults(100);
        samples = query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception exceptionGetSample) {
        logger.error("Exception while retrieving the records", exceptionGetSample);

    }
    return samples;
}
```

When I executed it with oracle db an error occur :

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException:
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

1. If I executed it only with lockmode parameter no error occurred.
2. If I executed it only with maxResult parameter no error occured.

I have used the eclipselink 2.5.0 library.

Please suggest some way so that I can use both the locking as well as can limit the records by using setMaxResults.

Comment: Does it produce the SQL statement? If it does, what is the generated SQL statement?

Comment: @Tiny Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Sample sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT /*+ FIRST_R
OWS */ a.*, ROWNUM rnum  FROM (SELECT ID AS a1, CREATEDAT AS a2, NAME AS a3 FROM
 ssohub.Sample ORDER BY CREATEDAT DESC FOR UPDATE) a WHERE ROWNUM <= ?) WHERE rnum > ?")

Answer (score 0):

See the below link for temporay resolution to the issue
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=453208#c7